# How to retrieve a record from a parent table based on its id on a child table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, relationship

I have two related models in a job listing application, Company and Listing. The relationship between them is that company may have listing and a listing must have exactly one company.

```
class Company extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'email',
        'website',
        'logo',
        'address',
        'city',
        'state',
    ];

    
    //Relationship to Listing
    public function listings(){
        return $this->hasMany(Listing::class, 'company_id');
    }
    //Relationship to company_image
    public function company_image(){
        return $this->hasMany(CompanyImage::class, 'company_id');
    }
    //Relationship to User
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

The listing model is defined as

```
class Listing extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    //Relationship to User
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    //Relationship to Company
    public function company(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id');
    }
```

I tried

```
public function edit(Listing $listing)
    {
        $cid = $listing->only(['id']); //to get the id of the company from the listings table
        $cid = $cid['id'];
        $comp =  Company::orderby('name','Asc')->get(); // this list all company in a select field
        $company = Company::whereHas('listings', function ($query) { //to get record of the company using the $cid from the listings table
            $query->where('listings.id','=',$cid);
        })->get();
        dd($company); //to check the value returned.
        // return view('listings.edit',[
        //     'listing' => $listing,
        //     'company' => $company, 
        //     'companys' => $comp
        // ]);
    }
```

i get an Undefined variable $cid when i use it like so where('listings.id','=',$cid).
i get null when i use it like so where('listings.id','=','$cid').

I want to get a result like

```
SELECT companies.name, companies.logo FROM companies join listings on listings.company_id = companies.id where listings.id = 4
```

which looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iigdJ.png)

Comment: I read Laravel doc and look up for some solutions but it they couldn't address solve my problem, probably i am mixing things up or missing somethings. I need reference to any resource from which i can get a basic lesson on relationships in Laravel 9.

Comment: try smh like this ````$listing = Listing::with('company')->where('id', $cid)->get()```` and in your company() function in listing model    ````return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id')->with('company_image');```` ps: don't forget to import listing model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you need to pass the variable to closure.

You can pass the variable using `use($variable)` after `function()`

```
$company = Company::whereHas('listings', function ($query) use ($cid){ 
        $query->where('listings.id','=',$cid);
    })->get();
```

Comment: This works well. Thank you you. I guess i have a lot to learn on Eloquent, if you you any resource that could help pls refer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just use your current code and access listing as below:

```
$some_id = 1;
$data = App\Models\Listing::find($some_id);
//For Name
$data->name;
//For images
$data->company->company_image;
```

Comment: Will try this when i get to company images models. I am still standing up the listing and companies functionalities.